# Recommended input frequency for games

Tags: performance, input

I am currently working on a project involving an embedded device sending input data to the computer, where this data should be processed to be sent to games.
I have the option to reduce the batter life of the device for extra frequency and stress tested the device to get an input frequency of about 25Hz.

Is 25Hz enough for games or should I strive for more?

Comment: I would worry more about latency than about frequency.

Comment: That's rather low, the default polling rate for a mouse is usually 125 Hz.  Gamers with deep pockets insist they need at least 500 Hz.  The SE gamers site is the more obvious place for a question like this.